# How to show a notification on receiving a new order

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce, uwp

I am writing app for UWP (C#), it's admin panel for restaurant. It needs to receive orders from WordPress website. I organized receiving from WooCommerce like this

```
public async void Down()
{
    RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
    WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
    //Get all products
    var orders = await wc.GetOrders();
    string date = orders[0].date_created + "+0:00";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
    string convertedDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    try
    {
        date1.Text = convertedDate;
        adress1.Text = orders[0].shipping.address_1.ToString() 
            + "                     " + orders[0].shipping.address_2;
        name1.Text = orders[0].billing.first_name.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

I need the app to monitor the creation of a new order and if there's a new order, give something like a pop-up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your application could be closed and you want to get message then you need to look at BackgroundTasks:
[Create and register a background task that runs in a separate process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task)

and you can use [TimeTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) to monitor new orders every 15 min.
or [MaintenanceTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger.aspxhttp://)

and show toast if there is new order with code like:

```
 void ShowToast(string whattext)
    {
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);
        XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(whattext));
        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

        toast.Activated += ToastActivated;
        toast.Dismissed += ToastDismissed;
        toast.Failed += ToastFailed;

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    }

    private void ToastFailed(ToastNotification sender, ToastFailedEventArgs args) { }
    private void ToastDismissed(ToastNotification sender, ToastDismissedEventArgs args) { }
    private void ToastActivated(ToastNotification sender, object args) { }
```

If you want to check orders in active application - just use [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx)

Comment: Okay. I make update on timer.  Where I need to paste code with Toast notification?

Comment: Inside dispatcherTimer_Tick event you can insert your Down() method

Comment: I done this and updating is working. I mean where I need to paste Toast notification?

I try to paste it in  'public sealed partial class InWork : Page'

It pasted well. When I try to paste it in Down() I have errors

Comment: Should be pasted inside class, not inside method. When you call ShowToast("some text there"); from Down() method you will get message

Comment: Great. It Works. Thak's